# Susy grid last column never gets filled

Tags: susy-compass

I've created a really simple grid with up to three columns, but I can never get anything to fill the last column except in the case of a single column.

[image: Three columns with third empty]
[image: Two columns with second empty]

Here you can see the two and three column layouts each with an empty column.

```
@import susy

+border-box-sizing

$total-columns  : 1
$column-width   : 20em
$gutter-width   : 1em
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width
$base-font-size : 20px
#grid
    +container(1, 2, 3)

.project
    +span-columns(1,1)
    @for $break from 2 through 3
        +at-breakpoint($break)
            +span-columns(1,$break)
```

Like I said, the grid is really simple. I feel I probably have a fundamental misunderstanding of how this works, but I have read over the documentation and many of the other Susy questions here to no avail.

My HTML output is generated by a CMS (Koken), but here's the markup of the grid itself.

```
<section id="portfolio">
    <div id="grid">
        <koken:load source="albums" filter:category="portfolio" limit="12">
            <koken:loop>
                <div class="project">
                    <koken:link>
                        <koken:img size="3:2" lazy="true" fade="200" />
                    </koken:link>
                    <h2>
                        <koken:link>
                            {{ album.title }}
                        </koken:link>
                    </h2>
                    <p>{{ album.description }}</p>
                </div>
            </koken:loop>
        </koken:load>
    </div>
</section>
```

Can anyone tell me how I might get my elements to utilize the final column of my grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the gutter (right-margin) from any element in the final column. You can do that several ways, depending what you need exactly:

```
.this-element {
  @include span-columns(1 omega);
}
```

or

```
.this-element {
  @include omega;
}
```

or, more likely in your case:

```
.these-elements {
  @include span-columns(1);
  @include nth-omega(#{$break}n);
}
```

But even that can get complex inside a loop like the one you have. So I recommend:

```
.these-elements {
  @include isolate-grid(1);
}
```

The isolation grid will work great in a loop, and will help fix any sub-pixel rounding errors along the way.

A few other comments on your code:

1. You only need to pass the context argument when you are not talking about the root context. In your sample, that means you don't need to pass context at all. You *can* if you find it easier to read, but it's not needed.
2. There is never any reason for a 1-column grid. At that width you simply don't need any grid, and you don't need Susy's help to achieve it. I would always set up Susy with the smallest multi-column grid you will need. Since the container is fluid below the first breakpoint, it will scale down for the one-column version.
3. No need to use Susy for full-width spans. Block elements span the full width by default.

In the end, I recommend something like this:

```
$total-columns: 2

#grid
  +container(2, 3)

.project
  // nothing here: block elements are full-width by default
  @for $break from 2 through 3
    +at-breakpoint($break)
      +isolate-grid(1)
```

Cheers!